# Как получить response используя axios + typescript?

Tags: typescript, axios

```
async function getSite(): Promise<any> {
    var result = await axios({
        url: 'https://example.com',
        method: "GET"
    }).catch((e) => {
        console.log(e)
    })

    console.log(response.data)
}
```

Однако при выводе появляется ошибка:

> Property 'data' does not exist on type 'void | AxiosResponse'.
> Property 'data' does not exist on type 'void'.

Answer (score 1):

Так как Вы гасите ошибку через catch, то соответственно в response может не быть `data`. Typescript об этом и намекает.

Во-первых (опечатка этот или нет не понятно) у Вас разные переменные. Вы кладете результат в `result`, а читаете из `response`.

Во-вторых попробуйте читать вот так

```
response?.data
```

Полный пример

```
import axios from 'axios';

async function getSite(): Promise<any> {
    const result = await axios({
        url: 'https://example.com',
        method: "GET"
    }).catch((e) => {
        console.log(e)
    })

    console.log(result?.data)
}
```

Comment: лучше `if (response && response.data)`

Comment: @Vadizar почему в асинхронной функции, при использовании оператора await "лучше через then"?

Comment: Возникает ошибка на 8 строчке кода (console.log(result?.data)): Property 'data' does not exist on type 'void | AxiosResponse<any>'.
  Property 'data' does not exist on type 'void'.

Comment: Можете сделать полный пример на https://jsfiddle.net/ ?